# Getting information 'randomly' placed inside a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to extract information from this string (was bytes, but I decoded it):

**\x00\x00\x00!broadcast "updatedirection 126.0"**

I need to see whether it contains **broadcast, updatedirection** and also see what the number is at the end. My first solutions were:

```
data = data.split('!')
data = data[1]
```

but the symbol in that position seemed to change randomly and with no apparent pattern at all. Then I tried:

```
data = data[12:]
```

But the string length changed all the time, so that didn't work.

I am doing this for a computer science project in school where I am using BYOB (based on Scratch, a simple language to teach young people how to program) and sockets to send data between them to make a LAN multiplayer. This is literally the only thing that doesn't work yet.

Hope someone can give me a solution to find this data.

Comment: Use a regular expression

Comment: `import re` `print re.findall('!broadcast "updatedirection [\d.]+"', INPUT)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hit it with a hammer

```
import re

s = '\x00\x00\x00!broadcast "updatedirection 126.0"'
pat = re.compile(r'(?:\x00){3}\Wbroadcast "updatedirection ([\d.]+)"')
m = pat.match(s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # '126.0'
```

Checking for different cases,

```
s = '\x00\x00\x00#broadcast "updatedirection 126.0"'
pat.match(s).group(1) # '126.0'

s = '\x00\x00\x00!foo "bar 126.0"'
pat.match(s) # None
```

You could make it more robust by changing the first part for null bytes of regex to something like giving it a range`(?:\x00){m,n}` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a string contains a word:

```
if word in string:
```

Then I would use [rfind()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) to find where the last space is, extract the text after this space and check whether it is a number.

You can test for both words in a single statement:

```
str = "test it here"

if "test" in str and "here" in str:
    print("they are")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import re

s = '\x00\x00\x00!broadcast "updatedirection 126.0"'

# if 'broadcast' in s  and 'updatedirection' in s:
if all([item in s for item in ['broadcast', 'updatedirection']]):
    result = re.findall('[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+', s)  # extract all numbers from a string

    print(result[-1]) # the last number
    # Output
    126.0
```

Refer to [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall).